Can't import module from within it in a poetry package
I have a poetry package that looks so:
recon/
 - pyproject.toml
 - recon/
  - main.py
  - config.py

From my main.py, I'm not able to do from recon.config import * - it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'recon.config'; 'recon' is not a package".
I tried adding:
packages = [
    { include = "recon" }
]

And running poetry -C recon/ install - no change.
For context, recon is part of my other project, so in reality the structure looks like this:
mainproject/
 - recon/
  - recon/
   - main.py

And I run main.py like this: poetry -C recon run python main.py. I've also tried to activate the virtualenv and run the file, still no luck.

Where does reconciliation come from? Could this be a typo somewhere or did you just shorten the name of your package for this question?

Ha you guessed right - I'm gonna edit it

There should be a recon/recon/__init__.py file to make it explicit that recon is an "import package". What is the name of the project in recon/pyproject.toml (i.e. name of the "distribution package")? -- You should run like this: poetry -C recon run python -m recon.main.
